# @ConditionalOnBean with @Bean does not work in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I was trying to use `@ConditionalOnBean` with `@Bean`, an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` occurred, then I tried to fix it and found the following situation.

1. When the fully qualified class name of `ExampleSupport` precedes the fully qualified class name of `ExampleProperties`, it working as expected. Such as:

   - Rename `ExampleSupport` to `ExampleConfig`
   - Move `ExampleSupport` to package `com.example.conditionexample.config`
2. Add the annotation `@Component`(or `@Service` ...) on the class `ExampleService` instead of using `@Bean` in `ExampleSupport`, it will also work as expected.

In addition, I found that the beanName `exampleProperties` is not included in `DefaultListableBeanFactory.beanDefinitionNames`. Why does `ConditionalOnBean` not take effect?

**Log**

```
2024-03-26T14:08:16.338Z  INFO 92687 --- [ConditionExample] [           main] c.e.c.ConditionExampleApplication        : Starting ConditionExampleApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 92687 (/Users/****/IdeaProjects/ConditionExample/target/classes started by **** in /Users/****/IdeaProjects/ConditionExample)
2024-03-26T14:08:16.340Z  INFO 92687 --- [ConditionExample] [           main] c.e.c.ConditionExampleApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-26T14:08:16.552Z  WARN 92687 --- [ConditionExample] [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleService' defined in class path resource [com/example/conditionexample/support/ExampleSupport.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'exampleService' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.conditionexample.support.ExampleProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-03-26T14:08:16.555Z  INFO 92687 --- [ConditionExample] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-26T14:08:16.568Z ERROR 92687 --- [ConditionExample] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method exampleService in com.example.conditionexample.support.ExampleSupport required a bean of type 'com.example.conditionexample.support.ExampleProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.conditionexample.support.ExampleProperties' in your configuration.
```

**Code**

ExampleProperties

```
package com.example.conditionexample.support;

@Getter
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnBean(ExampleService.class)
@Component
public class ExampleProperties {

    @Value("${example.property.integer}")
    private Integer integer;

}
```

ExampleService

```
package com.example.conditionexample.support;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ExampleService {

    /**
     * as an example，use {@code ApplicationContext} to represent a bean.
     */
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    private final ExampleProperties exampleProperties;
    
}
```

ExampleSupport

```
package com.example.conditionexample.support;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class ExampleSupport {

    @Bean
    public ExampleService exampleService(ApplicationContext context, ExampleProperties exampleProperties) {
        return new ExampleService(context, exampleProperties);
    }

}
```

ConditionExampleApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConditionExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConditionExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConditionExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ConditionExample</name>
    <description>ConditionExample</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Ofcourse this will fail, you have a circulair dependency now. The `@Conditional` depends on a bean that needs the conditional bean to be created in the first place.

Comment: Additionally the `ExampleSUpport` is annotated with `@Component` **not** `@Configuration` as it should. `@Bean` methods on `@Component` classes behave differently then on `@Configuration` classes. Nonetheless that wouldn't solve anything either as you still have the chicken/egg situation.

Comment: Specifically, `@Bean` on an `@Component` is ignored, isn't it?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) for `@ConditionalOnBean` says that you should only use it on an auto-configuration class (i.e. annotated with `@AutoConfiguration`), because `@ConditionalOnBean` checks the context at the time it is evaluated, and there's no guarantee that the target bean won't be created afterwards. `@AutoConfiguration` config classes are evaluated at the end, so all the non-conditional beans that should be created will already be created.

Comment: Ok. I realized what the problem was.